# UPDATE set FROM select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in MSSQL:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[sliders_item]
SET AdminCategoryLabel = st.Title
from [dbo].[sliders_item] si
inner join [dbo].[sf_content_link] cl on si.base_id = cl.parent_item_id
inner join [dbo].[sliders_type] st on cl.child_item_id = st.base_id
```

Wich works well when `sf_content_link` have one record with `si.base_id = cl.parent_item_id`.

I have to update `AdminCategoryLabel` using the connection table `sf_content_link` for the case when `sf_content_link` have many records with `si.base_id = cl.parent_item_id`. Somehow i have to select all the `Titles` from `sliders_type` and concatenate them to replace the current `st.Title` wich takes only first record.

Any idea how to do that?

The tables designs are:

- `sliders_item`: `base_id`, `AdminCategoryLabel`
- `sliders_type`: `base_id`, `Title`
- `sf_content_link`: `id`, `parent_item_id` (FK for `sliders_item base_id`), `child_item_id` (FK for `sliders_type base_id`).

Comment: I think it should be `UPDATE [dbo].[sliders_item] AdminCategoryLabel SET st.Title = (SELECT ... rest of your code .... )`

Comment: @PatrickHofman he said MSSQL -> Ms sql server

Comment: Yes simsim, something like that, but the select is the problem :(